# Fullscreen of nav + cover

Tags: tailwind-css

I need to have a screen that has top bar as a menu, that is a `ul` of `my-10`, and the rest of the screen is a `div` with a background image. Together they should cover `h-screen`.
What classes should I give to the nav, and what to the `div` containing the image?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the code of what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by display type of `flex`.

For your scenario:

Use a `nav`and a `div` which is inside the parent element of `flex flex-col h-screen`
And then give following classes for `nav` and `div`

- `nav -> flex`
- `div -> flex-1`

Try the following simple code:

```
<div className="flex flex-col h-screen">
  <nav class="flex items-center justify-between bg-white h-20 shadow-2xl">
    <div class="logo">
      <h1 class="text-black ml-4 cursor-pointer text-2xl">Logo here</h1>
    </div>
    <ul class="flex">
      <li>
        <a
          class="text-white mr-4 bg-gray-500 pt-4 p-4 pr-5 pl-5 hover:bg-gray-600 transition-all rounded"
          href="#"
        >
          <i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a
          class="text-white mr-4 bg-gray-500 pt-4 p-4 pr-5 pl-5 hover:bg-gray-600 transition-all rounded"
          href="#"
        >
          <i class="fas fa-question"></i> About
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a
          class="text-white mr-4 bg-gray-500 pt-4 p-4 pr-5 pl-5 hover:bg-gray-600 transition-all rounded"
          href="#"
        >
          <i class="fas fa-reply"></i> Contact
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div className="flex-1  bg-black">
    <img
      src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/slides/041.jpg"
      className="min-w-full min-h-full"
      alt="..."
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

Output:

[image]

For more information about the `flex` class refer https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex